# ASP.NET Web API and Async Methods

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

I'm working on a server-side project with a database with 2 tables:

```
tbl_Search and tbl_Provide
```

Here is some more info:

```
tbl_Search = table for users that search for items.  
tbl_Provide = table for users that provide items.
```

So obviously I have 2 methods: `Search()` and `Provide()`.
By calling `Provide()`, the user and the item are registered in `tbl_Provide`.
By calling `Search()`, the user is registered in `tbl_Search` as well as searching for the item he's looking for in `tbl_Provide`.

Now, since those methods involve database access, I decided to run them asynchronously so they won't block the main thread. 
Also, each user has a rank.

**My problem:**

2 users or more would like to have the same item. In such situation, the user with the highest rank should be the one to have it.
Therefor, once the user finds the item he was looking for, he can't simply take it as there might be another user with a higher rank who should have it.
I'm kind of lost here, not sure how to solve it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you tried something?

Comment: Where are you lost? If 2 users want the same thing, check the rank and give it to the highest rank.

Comment: What is the problem? How to determine the higher rank or making async db calls?

Comment: My problem is to determine the higher rank. 1 way of solving this was that after a searcher has found the item, he should scan tbl_Search to see if there's another user with a higher rank who wants this item - however, this solution seems inefficient.

Comment: Then you should remove all those talking about async

Comment: How else can I do it? I don't want my server-side method to be sync because then every call to the DB would cause the server to be stuck